# How to generate multiple convex hulls to cover a 3D concave trimesh

Tags: 3d, geometry, physics, computational-geometry, bullet

I am working on a 3D physics simulation environment and have run into the problem of concave shapes being hard to model physically. I'm currently using Bullet Physics to do the heavy lifting and it does not support dynamic concave shapes at all.

My plan is to take the 3D trimesh of the shape and then generate a number of convex hulls that when taken together as a composite shape aproximate the form of the 3D trimesh.

My question is: Is there an existing algorithm to do this?

If not how might you go about it?

Comment: Found library that does this: https://github.com/kmammou/v-hacd